# How to reduce size of Meteor React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I work on a React + Meteor App, With time size of my folder increases and now it is of size 60.8GB.
Now I don’t want to delete the app because there are a lot of branches associated with the folder.

Sorry that information seemed insufficient.
I cannot share the repo as it is private but on my local machine Can I delete the local folder from the .meteor directory, that is the folder with size almost 59GB?

I am working on that folder for the last 1year so there are a lot of branches in the git gui. Can deleting branches help me reducing size of app folder?

So how can I reduce the size of my app/folder?

Thanks

Comment: That's not anywhere near normal... Maybe you're building and including the build folder in your build recursively?

Comment: Hi, do you can share the repo?

Comment: If you've been committing the project to source control then why not just checkout the project into a new directory?

Comment: You're going to have to give more information for anyone to help you. As others have said though, that's nowhere near normal